# C/C++ libraries to get playlist from Internet Radio & Podcast Feeds?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk, gstreamer

I am trying to create a small music manager in Linux. Therefore, I just want to ask if there is any C/C++ library that can help me fetch playlists from Internet Radio & Podcast. I am planning on getting the playlist and display it in a GtkTreeView.

Thank you for answering my question and you guys have a good day!

Comment: I may be wrong but most of the todays playlists are probably created using xml. So all you probably need is an XML library.

Answer (score 1):

There should be many lib, but i know only a few, i dont no how it would help u, i got these from some other forums, you may try http://musicnote.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html this link, There is also openAL hope so it'll help u.

Answer (score 1):

Look at mplayer/ffmpeg code. They do it somehow.